# Is there a HashSet in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, hashset

Is there a HashSet in Delphi?

I know using set can at most hold 255 items. Is there a HashSet in latest Delphi Compiler e.g. XE8, Seattle

Comment: AFAIK Delphi doesn't includes a HashSet implementation but you can try the [Spring4D](https://bitbucket.org/sglienke/spring4d) project which includes a `THashSet `

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The standard collections do not offer a generic set class. Third party collections libraries such as Spring4D do.

You can build a generic set class quite easily on top of `TDictionary<K, V>`. A bare bones version might look like this:

```
type
  TSet<T> = class
  private
    FDict: TDictionary<T, Integer>;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function Contains(const Value: T): Boolean;
    procedure Include(const Value: T);
    procedure Exclude(const Value: T);
  end;

....

constructor TSet<T>.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  FDict := TDictionary<T, Integer>.Create;
end;

destructor TSet<T>.Destroy;
begin
  FDict.Free;
  inherited;
end;

function TSet<T>.Contains(const Value: T): Boolean;
begin
  Result := FDict.ContainsKey(Value);
end;

procedure TSet<T>.Include(const Value: T);
begin
  FDict.AddOrSetValue(Value, 0);
end;

procedure TSet<T>.Exclude(const Value: T);
begin
  FDict.Remove(Value);
end;
```

I've not compiled this code, so you may need to fix any mistakes I made. You'll likely want to extend it to be more capable. But hopefully this can show you how to start.

Comment: I think looking for a generic set type also entails looking for set operations such as union, intersect and difference. Also, because of the sorted storage constaints, you get these operations in lograithmic time.

Comment: @nurettin I don't see any requirement for those operations in the question and my own hash set usage seldom requires them. Plenty of usage scenarios don't. Also I don't think there is a constraint that storage must be sorted. It seems like you might be discussing your own scenarios rather than those presented in this question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`TDictionary`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Generics.Collections.TDictionary) for that. Define the `TKey` type parameter to be the thing you want to track. The `TValue` type parameter can be anything; you won't be using it. (Perl also lacks a *set* type, and so convention is to use its *hash* type in the same manner I'm suggesting here.)

Call [`ContainsKey`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Generics.Collections.TDictionary.ContainsKey) to check membership. Use [`Add`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Generics.Collections.TDictionary.Add) or [`AddOrSetValue`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Generics.Collections.TDictionary.AddOrSetValue) to insert; [`Remove`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Generics.Collections.TDictionary.Remove) to delete.

It would be a trivial exercise to write a wrapper that hides the unused `TValue` parameter.