# What Delphi type for 'set of integer'?

Tags: delphi, types

I have several hardcoded validations like these:

```
const
  cLstAct      =  1;   
  cLstOrg      =  4;
  cLstClockAct = 11;
const
  FUNCT_1 = 224;
  FUNCT_2 = 127;
  FUNCT_3 =   3;

if lFuncID in [FUNCT_1,FUNCT_2,FUNCT_3] then ...
if not (lListType in [cLstAct..cLstOrg,cLstClockAct]) then ...
if not (lPurpose in [0..2]) then ...
```

that I want to replace with a common method like

```
function ValidateInSet(AIntValue: integer; AIntSet: @@@): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (AIntValue in AIntSet);
  if not Result then ...
end;
```

but what type to choose for `AIntSet`?

Currently the values to be tested throughout the code go up to a const value 232 (so I can e.g. use a TByteSet = Set of Byte), but I can foresee that we will bump into the `E1012 Constant expression violates subrange bounds` when the constant values exceed 255.

My Google-fu fails me here...

(Currently on Delphi Seattle Update 1)

Comment: Spring4D has a THashSet: http://www.devjetsoftware.com/docs/spring4d/index.htm?Spring.Collections.Sets.THashSet%28T%29.IsSupersetOf.htm

Comment: Funny that AFAIR in FPC one can create as large sets as the memory would manage to contain. Though I am not sure that this specific Delphi limitation is not really an advantage...

Comment: You could use the generic set [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19524788/576719).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an `array of Integer`:

```
function ValidateInSet(AIntValue: integer; AIntSet: array of Integer): Boolean;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := False;
  for I := Low(AIntSet) to High(AIntSet) do
  begin
    if AIntSet[I] = AIntValue then
    begin
      Result := True;
      Break;
    end;
  end;
  if not Result then ...
end;
```

```
const
  cLstAct      =  1;   
  cLstOrg      =  4;
  cLstClockAct = 11;
const
  FUNCT_1 = 224;
  FUNCT_2 = 127;
  FUNCT_3 =   3;

if ValidateInSet(lFuncID, [FUNCT_1, FUNCT_2, FUNCT_3]) then ...
if not ValidateInSet(lListType, [cLstAct, 2, 3, cLstOrg, cLstClockAct]) then ...
if not ValidateInSet(lPurpose, [0, 1, 2]) then ...
```

Comment: I'm going for this solution since it fits best fits my existing code; no need to define and fill structures beforehand (like I would have to to if I e.g. used a TDictionary).
The only things I had to change were e.g. `if not ValidateInSet(lPurpose,[0..2],'purpose',false)` to `if not ValidateInSet(lPurpose,[0,1,2],'purpose',false)`

Answer (score 8):

Use a dictionary, `TDictionary<Integer, Integer>`. The value is irrelevant and you only care about the key. If the dictionary contains a specific key then that key is a member of the set. Use `AddOrSetValue` to add a member, `Remove` to delete a member and `ContainsKey` to test membership.

The point of using a dictionary is that it gives you O(1) lookup.

You don't want to use this type directly as a set. You should wrap it in a class that just exposes set like capabilities. An example of that can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33530037/505088

Comment: `TDictionary<Integer, Byte>` would be better then

Comment: @arioch not really no

Comment: why ? for those integers that would be registered that should reduce the footprint.

Comment: @arioch alignment means there's no difference

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a recent Delphi version, you can use `TArray<Integer>`.

```
function ValidateInSet(AIntValue: integer; const AIntSet: TArray<Integer>): Boolean;
var
  N: Integer;
begin
  { option1 : if AIntSet is always sorted }
  result := TArray.BinarySearch(AIntSet, AIntValue, N);

  { option 2: works for any array }
  result := false;
  for N in AIntSet do begin
    if AIntValue = N then begin
      result := true;
      Break;
    end;
  end;

  if not Result then begin
    // ...
  end;
end;
```

Calling is merely the same as with a set (except for ranges):

```
  if ValidateInSet(lFuncID, [FUNCT_1,FUNCT_2,FUNCT_3]) then begin

  end;
```

Comment: I would argue strongly that O(1) access is important and since it is so easy to achieve it feels poor to have O(n) access.

Comment: Tried this, but does not work: incompatible types on your example statement, not to mention things like `ValidateInSet(lListType,[cLstAct..cLstOrg,cLstClockAct])`

Comment: Lots of syntactical confusion between arrays and sets due to rather weak design of array literals.

Comment: That's why I mentioned the ranges exception in my answer, which will work for real sets only. The example compiles perfect here on Seattle.

Answer (score 1):

The direct answer would be `TBits` class

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.Classes.TBits.Bits

> Note: This can only be used starting with Delphi XE4 though - http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=108829

However for your "Set of integers" it in most inflated case would take `2^31 / 8` bytes of memory (because negative values of integer would not be even considered), and that would be a lot...
So I hope you would never really want to have a set of the whole integer. Or you should invest into Sparse Arrays instead.

```
function ValidateInSet(const AIntValue: integer; const AIntSet: TBits): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (AIntValue >= 0) and (AIntValue < AIntSet.Size);
  if Result then
     Result := AIntSet.Bits[AIntValue];
  if not Result then ...
     v-a-l-i-d-a-t-e
end;
```

or rather

```
function ValidateInSet(const AIntValue: integer; const AIntSet: TBits): Boolean;
begin
  Result := false;

  if AIntValue < 0 then exit;               // Validation criterion #1
  if AIntValue >= AIntSet.Size then exit;   // Validation criterion #2
  if not AIntSet.Bits[AIntValue] then exit; // Validation criterion #3

  if .... then exit;                        // Validation criterion #4
  if .... then exit;                        // Validation criterion #5
  if .... then exit;                        // Validation criterion #6

  Result := true;
end;
```

or perhaps

```
TSetTestCriterion = TFunc<Integer, Boolean>;
TSetTestCriteria  = TArray<TFunc<Integer, Boolean>>;

function ValidateInSet(const AIntValue: integer; 
     const AIntSet: TBits; const Tests: TSetTestCriteria = nil): Boolean;
var ExtraTest: TSetTestCriterion;
begin
  Result := false;

  if AIntValue < 0 then exit;               // Validation criterion #1
  if AIntValue >= AIntSet.Size then exit;   // Validation criterion #2
  if not AIntSet.Bits[AIntValue] then exit; // Validation criterion #3

  if Tests <> nil then           // Validation criteria #4, #5, #6, ...
    for ExtraTest in Tests do
      if not ExtraTest(AIntValue) then exit;        

  Result := true;
end;
```

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.SysUtils.TFunc

Now - just for demo, in real app you would create those set and array once and cache for long (forever, or at least unless the configuration change would demand rebuilding them).

```
Type FuncIDs = ( FUNCT_3 =   3, FUNCT_2 = 127, FUNCT_1 = 224);

var MysticGlobalFlag: Boolean;

function ValidateFuncID( const lFuncID: FuncIDs): Boolean;
var map: TBits;
begin
  map := TBits.Create;
  try
    map.Size := High(lFuncID) + 1;
    map.Bits[ Ord(Func_1) ] := True;
    map.Bits[ Ord(Func_2) ] := True;
    map.Bits[ Ord(Func_3) ] := True;

    Result := ValidateInSet( Ord(lFuncID), map,
       TSetTestCriteria.Create(
          function( lFuncID: integer) : Boolean
          begin
            Result := MysticGlobalFlag or (lFuncID <> Ord(FuncIDs.FUNC_2))
          end
       , 
          function( lFuncID: integer) : Boolean
          begin
            Result := (lFuncID <> Ord(FuncIDs.FUNC_3)) or (DayOfTheWeek(Now()) = 4)
          end
       )
    );
  finally
    map.Destroy;
  end;

  if not Result then  // from the original question code
     ...              // seems like a placeholder for error handling or object creation and registration
end;
```

Comment: I don't understand why your functions to check whether a value is in a set are so complicated.

Comment: Because topic starter added special processing after the failed search. Anyway,  removing extra tests is a breeze. However TS wanted the same function work with different domains and then extensibility is a good thing to have

Comment: Note that [QualityCentral has now been shut down](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/quality-keeps-moving-forward), so you can't access `qc.embarcadero.com` links anymore. If you need access to old QC data, look at [QCScraper](http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2017/06/09/how-to-save-qualitycentral/).

Comment: yep, they don't want public annonymous users to look into their bugs :-)

Answer (score 0):

All, I know it's years since people answered this, but here is a new solution using Delphi generics: -

```
interface
uses
  System.Generics.Defaults;

type
  TUtilityArray<T> = class
  public
    class function Contains(const x : T; const an_array : array of T) : boolean;
  end;

implementation

class function TUtilityArray<T>.Contains(const x: T; const an_array: array of T): boolean;
var
  y          : T;
  l_comparer : IEqualityComparer<T>;
begin
  Result     := false;
  l_comparer := TEqualityComparer<T>.Default;
  for y in an_array do
  begin
    if l_comparer.Equals(x, y) then
    begin
      Result := true;
      break;
    end;
  end;
end;



end.
```

To use include the class, then write `if(TUtilityArray<integer>.Contains(some integer value, [value1, value2 etc.])) then ...`.  An added benefit of this method is that it works for other primitives as well.