# Is there a sorted collection in Delphi, like C++'s std::set?

Tags: delphi, data-structures, collections

I need a container that will contain sorted integers, so it will be fast to search if an integer is already in this set. Does Delphi have a collection for that, which is similar to C++'s [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set)?

First, I thought that Delphi's [`Set`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)) is what I need, but when I tried:

```
Type
  TIntSet = set of Integer;
```

I get an error:

> [dcc64 Error]  Sets may have at most 256 elements

Comment: Delphi in particular, or any Object Pascal language (Free Pascal, Oxygene, and of course Delphi)?

Comment: There is [System.Generics.Collections.TList](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Generics.Collections.TList)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66017283/282848

Comment: Do you need them sorted? Or do you just want fast access?

Comment: That kind of collection is generally implemented via a red-black tree and Delphi has no native support for them.

Comment: Will you update the collection frequently or will it be used in read-only mode after it is contructed?

Comment: @Olivier I will update it not so frequently, but not once. Most of the time I will check if it contains a number.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the latter. Most of the time I will check does it contain a certain number.  Anf from time to time new element will be added.

Comment: You can use the generic set from spring4d which is a hashed collection giving O(1) access. That library also has a good red black tree implementation but I don't think you have any need for that since you don't need the collection to be sorted.

Comment: If you don't need sorting, why did you say the opposite in the question? You could just use a [`TDictionary`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Generics.Collections.TDictionary) (which is a hash table).

Comment: Your actual question is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33529763/is-there-a-hashset-in-delphi).

Comment: @Olivier as I don't need a key-value pair I didn't thought of using TDictionary.

Comment: TBits from the System.Classes unit could be a good choice